# CABasicAnimation byValue strange behavior

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I was reading the [12th number of Objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html) and encountered a problem when trying the first pieces of code.
In the first part "A Basic Animation" the last piece of code uses byValue to interpolate a property using initial property value and adding byValue.

So I tried the code in my project and discovered it wasn't working and had a really strange behavior.

Here's a very short gif illustrating the problem :

[image: Gif video illustrating the bug]

And here's the only code I'm using :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var rocket1: UIView!
    var rocket2: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        rocket1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 50, height: 20))
        rocket1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        rocket2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: 50, height: 20))
        rocket2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        self.view.addSubview(rocket1)
        self.view.addSubview(rocket2)

    }

    @IBAction func button() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
        animation.byValue = 300
        animation.duration = 1

        rocket1.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "basic")
        rocket1.layer.position.x += 300

        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5

        rocket2.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "basic")
        rocket2.layer.position.x += 300

    }
}
```

If you want to try the project here's the full project (use iPhone 6 simulator or shapes will be hidden because 5S is too "short") : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/378166/VCoreAnimation.zip

Comment: I don't find it that strange. It's pretty close to _the behavior_ of 'additive' animations, as [explained here](http://ronnqvi.st/multiple-animations/)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Really interesting thank you for linking for your article !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a completion block for this animation like this:

```
@IBAction func button() {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.byValue = 300
    animation.duration = 1

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        rocket1.layer.position.x += 300
    })
    rocket1.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "basic")
    CATransaction.commit()

    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        rocket2.layer.position.x += 300
    })
    rocket2.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "basic")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

In this case we need 2 CATransaction blocks since we have 2 animations running with a time diference from each other.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but isn't that strange that you have to do this ? When you use fromValue & toValue you don't need to use a completionBlock it just works without (because animation are started before you change the modelLayer).